# Adding onclick to all elements

Tags: javascript, html

i need to add onclick="window.location.href= to all elements on my page
I heard i need to use * for all elelemts
how will code look for me to make that? hope someone can help me

will aprecte help so much, im new to programming, just learning

Comment: are you sure that you are using Java? Or is it Javascript? Anyway, the question is not very specific, maybe add more details

Comment: i need to add onclick="window.location.href='https://website.com" to all buttons for example, not to do it 1 by 1, is it possible somehow?

Comment: all buttons on page should have  onclick="window.location.href='website.com"
or all clickable elements

Comment: im using HTML but i heard i have to make script with JS to make it work

Comment: as JS suggest, it is JavaScript not Java...

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, to add `window.location.href = "https://example.com"` to **every element** on your page, you need to use the `*` selector, as you mentioned. That will look something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', () => {
        window.location.href = 'https://website.com';
    });
});
```

That being said, it seems unnecessary to attach a click event to every single element, and probably makes more sense to attach the click event to the body element or the page itself.

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.location.href = 'https://website.com';
});
```

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.location.href = 'https://website.com';
});
```

If you simply meant you wanted to add it to every link or button on your page, and not actually every element, then something like this would work:

*You can substitute 'a' and 'button' in the code below with any element that you want to apply the click event to.*

```
const clickableElements = document.querySelectorAll('a, button');
clickableElements.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = 'https://website.com';
    });
});
```

Another method for catching the click event on multiple buttons is to add a click event to their parent div, and then check if the child element being clicked is a button.

```
const parentElement = document. getElementsByTagName('body');
parentElement.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const isButton = event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON';
  if (!isButton) {
    return;
  }
  window.location.href = 'https://website.com';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add a click event for all buttons, something like this will work:

```
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("button")).forEach((c) => {
    c.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        window.location.href="website.com";
    });
  });
```